# Quad precision normal cdf and quantile functions

Tags: normal-distribution, algorithms, cumulative-distribution-function

I'm looking to run the normal distribution cumulative distribution function and quantile function (its inverse) using the quadruple precision floating point format. Does anyone know of a library that does that, or an algorithm such that I could code my own?

Comment: The PDF is relatively easy: its just a square and an exponential.  The CDF is harder.  The references for the [Mathematical help page on the error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html) would be a good start.  The beginning of Acton's book, *Numerical Methods that Work*, uses computation of Erf (essentially the CDF) as a running example (beginning p. 14).  There likely is no single algorithm: different methods work better in different ranges, typically for $|x|\ll 1$, $|x|\approx 1$, and $|x|\gg 1$.

Comment: @whuber: Thanks! Just to be clear, I meant to ask about the PPF (Percent point function (inverse of cdf)), not the PDF. I edited my question to reflect that. I'm sorry for the confusion!

Comment: If you only need one-off results--or at least a way to check your answers--you can ask [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=CDF[NormalDistribution[0%2C1]%2C+2]) and then press the "More digits" button in the answer.

Comment: That's interesting to know about Wolfram Alpha! But it's not what I need... I need something preferably written in C so that it runs fairly quickly